# system.properties in AWS

Tags: tomcat, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, system-properties

Amazon elastic beanstalk tomcat java web application issue with system.properties. When I use system.getproperty("user.home") to access directory correctly to export a file in my java web application, i can test it fine when i run on localhost. After deploying App to AWS elastic beanstalk..user.home gives me this path **/usr/share/tomcat8**  and user as **tomcat**. Where as it should give **C:/users/myname** as user.home and **myname** as user. Please help. I am struggling from 2 days on this issue. Is it something to set up in AWS environmental properties ? or is there any other way to access local downloads folder in web application. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/share/tomcat8` it is Unix like file path, because on AWS your app runs on some kind of Linux. `C:/users/myname` is Windows like path.

That's normal and should be expected.

Accessing local downloads folder can be tricky as it is platform/OS dependent. Consider your app structure and how it should work as it is possible that you don't need this local downloads folder.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I am using a dynamic java web project. I need to export a excel file to the user. Any possible ways I can do it?